# Sdo_Geom.Sdo_Intersection is not considering overlapping vertices

Tags: intersection, overlapping-features, sdo-geometry

I'm using below package to get the number of intersecting vertices

```
Sdo_Util.Getnumvertices(Sdo_Geom.Sdo_Intersection(B.Geom,R.Geom,.00000000005))
```

It is returning only 1 when there are actually 15 vertices in B.Geom. I have validated this by using Sdo_Util.Getnumvertices(B.Geom) and is returning 15 vertices.

I'm a novice in Spatial database and not very sure if Sdo_Geom.Sdo_Intersection Will remove duplicates/overlapping vertices? I wnat to be able to consider all the overlapping vertices as well. Can anyone please let me know if i'm doing right thing here?

Please see below image of intersection where B.Geom is the point (has 15 overlapping vertices) & R.Geom is the polygon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that intersection is wrong function for you. Intersection is a new geometry and in your case it is a single point. Test by selecting Sdo_Geom.Sdo_Intersection(B.Geom,R.Geom,.00000000005) into Well Known Text. I guess that it will a a point.
BTW point can't have 15 overlapping vertices. Either it is a multipoint with 15 members or 15 distinct but overlapping points.

Comment: Sorry it was bit ambiguous, it is a multipoint with 15 members. However for my analysis I believe intersection is the only way. You know any function which does the same work?